# I started cooking my steak before adding seasoning, how can I save my meal?

Tags: steak, seasoning

I was having a busy day yesterday and wanted to cook a small sirloin steak. I preheated and oiled the skillet, patted dry my steak, got distracted by my dog, and put the steak in the skillet, unseasoned.

After searing I went to flip the meat and realized my error. In a panic I added my seasoning, flipped the steak over and went to season the now-seared side. It didn't stick to the meat well and in the end I ate a pretty bland steak.

If this happens again what can I do to recover from my error and save my meal?

Comment: Finish cooking, slice, season as you eat?

Comment: It's called peppercorn sauce.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Many people don't season their steaks before cooking and they still get tasty meat by seasoning it after. Salting beforehand helps release juices and gets a bit of flavor penetration, but it won't ruin it if you skip that step. Peppering before cooking is a bad idea anyway as the pepper will burn and turn bitter, so you should always pepper the steak straight after you take it off the pan.

Next time just finish cooking it and sprinkle some salt and pepper on it straight after cooking.

Comment: Good to know. I must've been overthinking it; I had always been told to start with seasoning

Comment: @PausePause if you are going to salt before make sure it's either right before you put it on or a long time before you cook.  Current wisdom suggests doing so a moderate amount of time before cooking is the worst option

Comment: @eps you should post this as an answer